# Accessing file system from Tomcat webapp deployed in OpenShift

Tags: tomcat, grails, openshift

I've deployed a Grails webapp into OpenShift's Tomcat 7 gear.

That app needs to read and write some files. I can't find where is the Tomcat working folder to create some initial files, so I can see them from my app in Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interact with underlying filesystem through your grails app using OpenShift's [environment variables](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html).
To create a file/folder in a persistence storage, use "OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR" environment variable inside your app.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that jbossews was my working folder. Maybe is because I'm using a Tomcat7 cartridge.